# ASUS Xtion Pro -- need help?

Tags: ros, asus-xtion-pro-live, ros-groovy, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Kinect/Xtion noob here, I am starting out with ASUS Xtion Pro Live -- any help or suggestion on where to start ? Any step by step tutorial ??

I am on Ubuntu 12.04 and can work on ROS Fuerte and also on ROS Groovy.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52097/asus-xtion-pro----need-help-!/) by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1108 on 2013-01-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just download openni_camera and openni_launch packages from the ROS repository and then try:
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch

the openni_node will provide you different topics including depth,RGB,disparity,IR and ...

---

Originally posted by [Alireza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1637/alireza/) with karma: 717 on 2013-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2013-01-15**:
@Alireza So, I plug it in and run the node ? simple !!!